# split string into multiple column without delimiter bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i wanted to split below string into multiple column like without delimiter

having data like

```
error
4126
26
42
1451
12214126
```

and wanted like this

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
41        26        
26          
42          
14        51        
12        21      41      26
```

how can i achive this in bigquery

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below, I hope, will give you something to learn

```
select * from (
  select error, code, offset
  from data, unnest(regexp_extract_all(error, r'\d{2}')) code with offset
)
pivot (max(code) for offset in (0,1,2,3))
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a substring operation:

```
select substr(error, 1, 2) as col1,
       substr(error, 3, 2) as col2,
       substr(error, 5, 2) as col3,
       substr(error, 7, 2) as col4
from t;
```

Using arrays and regular expressions seems like overkill for this.